# A GUI application, which runs on SQL queries

Tags: mysql, user-interface

I have few simple queries, that display rows from a table in a database. I want to create an executable GUI which shows the results of these queries. Suppose, if I type the name in the dialog box of the application, it should show the rows in the table having that name.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Figure out an appropriate development environment for your chose operating system.  For Windows, you could go with something like Access, but the Visual Studio Express editions should work fine.  For Linux, or a cross-platform app, I'd suggest something like Java.  You could code it up as a web app if you have a web server.  For mobile devices, you'll need some environment capable of churning out code on that device (Eclipse with the Android development tools, Xcode on a Mac, etc.).

Step 2: Write the app to take the input and show you the data.

Unfortunately, without any indication of what OS or database system you're running or what development tools you have access to or are willing to buy, that's about as specific an answer as we can give.